# Effciently search a string for a set of chars and return the first match

Tags: string, performance, lua, match

I'm implementing a vt100 (oldschool terminal) into lua, which runs on a embedded MCU. Performance is an issue here.

Given is a string ( input line) which contains several ( unpredictable number ) characters.
In this string, I want to find the first match, out of a set of characters.

For example:

```
-- ASCII value(hex) of keyboard keys.
#define KEY_UP      "\x41"
#define KEY_DOWN    "\x42"
#define KEY_RIGHT   "\x43"
#define KEY_LEFT    "\x44"

-- terminal object is defined and created

function terminal:receive()
    -- Set buffer and shorthand to self.port.read
    local read = function() return self.port:read() end
    local received = ""

    while true do
        -- Read Input
        local line = read()
        if ( not line ) then break end
        received = received .. line

        -- Search for the key.
        -- Don't search in line, due different baudrates might not
        -- Get the entire digit at once.
        if ( received:find( KEY_UP ) ) then
            return KEY_UP
        elseif ( received:find( KEY_DOWN ) ) then
            return KEY_DOWN
        ... and so on
        end
    end
end
```

The solution in my example is kind of slow, surely. It's not that hard to come up with more performant solutions. But what is the most performant solution for this?

Comment: Have you used any profilers? Are you sure the pattern matching part is the performance bottleneck here?

Comment: It's probably not, but that's another question.

Comment: I'm just concerned by the matching at the first glance, due I'm searching for like 40 keys. If the match is one of the first keys, it's surely quiet fast and the receiving process might be the bottleneck. However, if there is no match, there have been 40 :find()s, which take more than a couple of ticks.

Comment: Why do you put your string together at first and parse it later? Why don't check for keys right after reading the input?

Comment: Because of brain malfunction.... Thanks a lot for the hint. However, this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Sempie: You can use a single `:find()` instead of 40 if you put all keys in a single pattern ...

Answer (score 1):

Since all your matches are one char long, you can use set `[]` to match and capture `()` to see what you did match.

```
#define KEY_UP      "\x41"
#define KEY_DOWN    "\x42"
#define KEY_RIGHT   "\x43"
#define KEY_LEFT    "\x44"
-- assemble pattern once for performance
local KEY_pattern = "([" .. KEY_UP .. KEY_DOWN .. KEY_RIGHT .. KEY_LEFT .. "])"

-- ............... skipped ...............
local match_start, match_end, match_content = received:find(KEY_pattern)
if ( match_content )  then
    return match_content
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a single pattern containing all the characters you are looking for. You can then capture the result and return it.

This works, if you don't have any priority order among the characters you are looking for.